# How to add one html element in multiple files at once

Tags: html, frameworks, structure

I want to add new item to my nav-bar which is made in bootstrap. With several files it isn't a big deal, however the problem arises when we've got a dozen or so html files with the same navbar. Now if I add Item 2 to the index.html I would have to copy paste it on every subpage. Are there any tools that could make it quicker?

To exemplify here is a sample code for one html file:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Sounds like you need a templating engine :D

Comment: @grooveplex probably, would you happen to have a recommendation?